# How to fetch all text from the DOCX as-is

Tags: java, docx4j

I have a word document with sample text from new york times like below:

> Sample Text:
>
> KABUL, Afghanistan – Secretary of State John Kerry began a series of
>   meetings in Kabul on Friday in hopes of finding a way out of a
>   presidential election crisis that has threatened to split the Afghan
>   government and prompted Western officials to warn that Afghanistan
>   risked losing billions of dollars in air on which it depends.

When I upload the document to docx4java online demo I get the following PartsList:

```
<w:p w14:paraId="4CB9CEA6" w14:textId="77777777">
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>Sample Text:</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
                <w:p w14:paraId="0F399D69" w14:textId="77777777"/>
                <w:p w14:paraId="0C68A7DC" w14:textId="6C93B9E5">
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>KABUL, Af</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>g</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t xml:space="preserve">hanistan – Secretary of State John Kerry began a series of meetings in Kabul on Friday in hopes of finding a way out of a presidential election crisis that has threatened to split the Afghan government and prompted Western officials to warn that Afghanistan risked losing billions of dollars in air on which it depends. </w:t>
                    </w:r>
                    <w:bookmarkStart w:name="_GoBack" w:id="0"/>
                    <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
                </w:p>
```

Note how the word `Afghanistan` is broken into three different tags? I'm not sure why that happens.

I am extracting text from this docx using docx4j with the code below:

```
StringBuilder builder;
class DocumentTraverser  extends TraversalUtil.CallbackImpl {
    @Override
    public List<Object> apply(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof org.docx4j.wml.Text) {
            builder.append(((org.docx4j.wml.Text) o).getValue());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Using this code `builder` has the following content:

> Sample Text:KABUL, Afghanistan – Secretary of State John Kerry began a
>   series of meetings in Kabul on Friday in hopes of finding a way out of
>   a presidential election crisis that has threatened to split the Afghan
>   government and prompted Western officials to warn that Afghanistan
>   risked losing billions of dollars in air on which it depends.

However, This text isn't AS-IS what the docx contains. `Sample Text:KABUL` should not be one word.

**Question**

Is there a way to extract text from the DOCX as-is ? Meaning all the words be separated just the way they are in the original document?

Answer (score 2):

You should encorporate **paragraph breaks**: `</w:p>`. As I do not have docx4j on my machine, the following is more of an idea:

```
public List<Object> apply(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof org.docx4j.wml.Text) {
        builder.append(((org.docx4j.wml.Text) o).getValue());
    } else if (o instanceof Element)
        && ((Element) o).getTagName().equals("w:p") {
        builder.append("\n");
    }
    return null;
}
```

This adds a linefeed at the beginning of a paragraph; but look how you may improve that.

By the way, check for `<w:t>` only, as there is also special **command** `Text`.

Also **page breaks** (`"\f"`) may be added on `<w:lastRenderedPageBreak>`.